# Display video from a webpage in android videoview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview, android-video-player

I know how to display a video in a video view as following

```
<VideoView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/VideoView">
    </VideoView>
```

In my activity I am using

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
String uriPath = "http://url.to.myvideo.mp4";
android.net.Uri uri = android.net.Uri.parse(uriPath);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView.start();
```

I am looking for a way to play video in a videoview from a webpage that has video for example the page has a video https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-africa-55085946

Is there any way to play the video present in the webpage in a videoview?

Comment: this might help - https://github.com/friederbluemle/video-enabled-webview/tree/update-project